# Angular Universal

Tags: angular, google-search

У гугла есть проблема с индексацией приложений на angular и вообще SPA. У angular есть такой модель как angular universal. Как пишут в доках, проблема индексации решается с этим модулем и индексация вообще происходит на скомпилированном на стороне сервера приложением. Дак вот вопрос.. правда ли это и действительно ли совсем не будет с этим модулем проблем? 
Например, у меня есть какая-то информация, хранится она в json файле и в приложение добавляется только по нажатию на кнопку какую-то. Найдет ли гугл эту информацию при просмотре моей страницы своим роботом при использовании мной вышеупомянутого модуля?

Comment: нет, не найдет, сервер рендерит страницу один раз, а все то, что добавляется по нажатию кнопки - это динамика

Comment: Есть ли какой-то способ решить эту проблему? На сайте, к примеру, будет несколько языковых версий, каждая, понятное дело, загружается по нажатию на кнопку соотв. Как мне рассказать гуглу информацию на каждом языке? В таком случае angular бесполезен со всем его сервисом переводов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы интегрировать `Universal` в существующий проект - нужно понять для чего он нужен и как он работает. `Universal` в действительности нужен в случаях, когда в требованиях проекта есть индексирование сайта поисковыми роботами и тд. Я использую `Universal` на работе в проектах, где клиент хочет что-то публиковать на `Facebook` или `Twitter`, от мета тегов, которые вставляются динамически в рантайме нет толку для парсеров. `Universal` - один из самых сложных инструментов в семействе пакетов `@angular/*`.

Что он делает? Под капотом `@angular/platform-server` всего навсего использует уже готовые средства из пакета `@angular/core`:

```
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';

renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    url: '/',
    document: readFileSync('./index.html').toString()
}).then((html) => console.log(html));
```

Единственная функция, которая в основном используется для работы с `Universal`, первым аргументом принимает скомпилированную фабрику корневого модуля, вторым аргументом - опции, например для какого роута рендерить страницу. В конечном итоге  используя генератор событий `isStable` (свойство класса `ApplicationRef`), когда Angular построил DOM для текущего роута - `Universal` использует сервис `Document`, который можно заинжектить через токен `@Inject(DOCUMENT)`, для конвертации DOM в строку через `Document.prototype.serialize`.

У него есть свои подводные камни, на которые все натыкаются выходя в плавание:

```
<h1 *ngIf="true">Меня увидят?</h1> <-- будет в дереве

<h1 [hidden]="true">Меня увидят?</h1> <-- будет в дереве

<h1 *ngIf="shouldShow">Меня увидят?</h1> <-- не будет в дереве, если `shouldShow = false`

<button (click)="shouldShow = true">Показать</button>
```

По поводу вашего вопроса с информацией и нажатием кнопки, представим любой файл с `json`:

```
// information.json

{
    "information": {
        "shouldUseGraphQL": true,
        "version": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Компонент:

```
import { information } from './information.json';

class Component {
    public information: Information | null = null;

    public showInformation(): void {
        this.information = information;
    }
}
```

Шаблон:

```
<h1 *ngIf="information">{{ information | json }}</h1>
<button (click)="showInformation()">Показать информацию</button>
```

Информация пользователю показывается после нажатия кнопки, соответственно на этапе изначального рендеринга `information` у нас `null`, `Universal` натыкается на такую конструкцию и 'вырезает' тег `h1`. Окей, как быть? Мы можем сделать так, чтобы инфомарция была в дереве, но показывалась только по условию:

```
import { information } from './information.json';

class Component {
    public information: Information = information;

    public shouldHideInformation = true;

    public showInformation(): void {
        this.shouldHideInformation = false;
    }
}
```

Шаблон:

```
<h1 [hidden]="shouldHideInformation">{{ information | json }}</h1>
<button (click)="showInformation()">Показать информацию</button>
```

В данном случае если нажать `Ctrl + U` в браузере и посмотреть на DOM, то этот `h1` там будет, только не будет виден пользователю в браузере из-за атрибута `hidden`.

Если вы работаете с мультиязычностью, то динамика тут никак не поможет. Можно использовать связку `@ngx-translate + TransferState`. Например у пользователя на странице будет какой-то `select` с возможностью выбора языка, он выбирает язык, меняется язык в приложении + в куках устанавливается язык, который он выбрал, в следующий раз при перезагрузке страницы в хедеры `accept-language` можно устанавливать его выбранный язык и `Universal` будет возвращать вам `html` с нужным переводом. Но если нужно, чтобы разные версии индексировались поисковиками, то тут только делать разные версии сайтов, в смысле русский язык у вас будет по роуту `mysite.com/ru`, а английский `mysite.com/en`, потому что поисковик не сможет тыкать кнопки и выбирать нужный ему язык :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснения. Но вот как раз самая главная проблема кроется в том, что вы написали в последних предложениях. То есть, по сути, при использовании сервиса переводчика ngx от angular на индексацию google рассчитывать не придется?

Comment: можно рассчитывать на индексацию если сделать разные версии сайтов, но увы если приложение просто одностраничное (без каких-либо роутов), то гугл будет индексировать страницу с языком, который загружается изначально, но в примере с `/ru` и `/en` - так сделать не очень сложно, по сути у вас будет `path: ':lang', component: Component, children: [{ ... }]`, при иницилазации класса `Component` - инжектить `ActivatedRoute` и брать параметры из урла (`this.route.snapshot.params.lang => ru | en`)

Comment: Вот оно! Спасибо за объяснения еще раз, и особенно за последнюю подсказку! Как я сам не додумался! 
Спасибо!!